# Google Big Table Vs Big Query for ad server data analysis

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-bigtable

We are looking to build a solution on GCP for campaign/ad analytics (ingest doubleclik and other ad-server data into DW). Data is ingested as batch, with star schema but will have updates trickling in for up to a week, need trend analysis for multiple clients (advertisers) and reporting. I can't decide between Google Big table which supports updates and timeseries analysis Vs Big Query which is ideal for star schema and ad-hoc analysis.

Any suggestions? Performance and flexibility are important.

Comment: This past thread may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437572/google-bigtable-vs-bigquery-for-storing-large-number-of-events. Note that BigQuery does allow for updates too; in addition to appending data, you can use DML to modify existing data if you need: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=657.

Comment: I believe they have a cloud connector (might still be in beta) that can automatically dump DFP logs into BigQuery in a similar manner to how they dump GA data into daily tables for GA premium subscribers. 

I'd reach out to someone from Google cloud if you can.

Comment: Also there are some managed service approaches to this with people like switchboard-software.com I've dealt with them and they know this stuff inside out.

Comment: P.s I'd go with Google data flow (apache beam) + big query

Answer (score 1):

You may find the following solution guide helpful for learning how to build an analysis pipeline using BigQuery and other GCP products and tools:

- https://cloud.google.com/solutions/marketing-data-warehouse-on-gcp

Bigtable meanwhile is a good fit for building real-time bidding and other pieces of core ad serving infrastructure. See e.g.:

- https://cloud.google.com/customers/mainad/
- https://cloud.google.com/solutions/infrastructure-options-for-building-advertising-platforms