# How to use BigTable from the spring boot application?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable, spring-cloud-gcp

I was investigating ["What's the difference between BigQuery and BigTable?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39926480/2674303).

And found that BigTable is like traditional database.

Also I found that for current moment [Spring supports BigQuery](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gcp#overview) but doesn't support BigTable. It is a bit surprising for me. Could you please explain why?

Is there way to use BigTable from spring boot application?

Comment: if the question how can you access big table from a spring boot application why cant you just use their java client? https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java

Comment: If you are wondering how you can seamlessly connect it with Spring you could just create Java Configuration and create BigtableDataSettings bean, you can inject properties from application.yml  from there you can create bean: BigtableDataClient and reuse it in services, or wherever seems fit.